# Schengen travel for holder of Greek Blue Paper (Marriage)

Tags: schengen, greece, greek-citizens, tunisian-citizens

I am a Tunisian citizen working in Greece and holding the blue paper. I am married to a Greek citizen and now waiting for the Residence permit. As far as I know, I am able to go back to my home country and other visa-free destinations (Turkey, Morocco etc). While I wait for my residence permit, am I allowed to travel to schengen countries if accompanied by my Greek partner? I appreciate your help :) Cheers!

Comment: Questions about residence permits are off-topic, here, so I edited them out of your question. You can ask about those things on [expatriates.se].